# Do not select a default value for a dropdownlist in sugarcrm

Tags: drop-down-menu, default-value, sugarcrm

When generate a list of radio (with a dropdownlist), it will select a default value automatically.

But I do not want to select any values as default, how to set this?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to solve this from Studio is to add an empty row to your drop down list. If this is not preferred, then I would follow Jim's suggestion to affect all the drop downs to not contain a default value. To get the wanted affect to this single drop down then JavaScript code would be the proper tool.

Comment: The 'blank' option at the top of the dropdown list menu is the best practice for this. It forces the user to select a "real" value, keeps the database clean, etc.

Comment: But it will display as radio buttons list, not a select drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

It will be radio buttons. Not a drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there's no way to set this in studio.

You can set this in the database as a quick and dirty fix:

```
UPDATE fields_meta_data SET default_value = '' WHERE id = 'IDOFCUSTOMFIELD';
```

Nicer, but more involved would be to create a custom version of

```
modules/DynamicFields/templates/Fields/Forms/enum.tpl
```

which allows choosing no default value.

Answer (score 0):

One way we've done this by adding a value in studio of "please_select" with a display label of "-please select-" and make this the default.

This way it's obvious when staff are looking at the record that it's not filled in, and we use workflows and reports to catch the exceptions and raise the alert to the appropriate person/s.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this, although I would like to stress that I would not recommend this as a best practice.

I was using SuiteCRM 7.2.3, and Sugar 6.5.20. So not sure whether this will work in later Sugar Versions.

1. Create a Radio Drop Down Field
2. Create your drop down list
3. Save it
4. Go back in the dropdown editor and find your dropdown list: In my
   example, I had options, 0, 1, and 2.
5. Create the same options again only as 3, 4, and 5.
6. Now delete options 0, 1, and 2.
7. Save the dropdown

MAKE SURE you don't save the field again after you do this, only the dropdown list.

Now go look at the field in the EditView and you'll see that no option is selected. Worked every time I did this. Nothing shows up in the DetailView, so I'm assuming `NULL` is being passed to the DetailView in this instance, but I'm not 100% sure.